# Further problems with reading multiple pages with rvest

Tags: function, dplyr, rvest

In trying to access all pages through the json object, I get various error codes

This code works:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)
library(rjson)
library(tidyverse)


body_tags_1 <- lapply(paste0('https://www.eventbrite.com/d/ny--new-york/conference/?page=', 1:49),
                function(url){
                  url %>% read_html() %>% 
                    html_nodes("body") %>% 
                    html_text() %>% 
                    toString() # to produce a single character string describing an R object.
                })

# str_match_all - Extract matched groups from a string.
# output - a list of character matrices
# search window Server data for all items
tmp <- str_match_all(body_tags_1,'window.__SERVER_DATA__ = (.*?);')
```

I have tried these lines of code to read all 49 lines

```
json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp)
```

Error message:

```
Error in file(tmp) : invalid 'description' argument
```

```
json <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines(tmp), collapse=",")))
```

Error message:

```
Error in readLines(tmp) : 'con' is not a connection
```

```
for (k in 1:49){
   json[[k]] <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp[[k]][,2], flatten=TRUE) 
}
```

Error message:

```
Error: object 'json' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like as follows where you end up with a list of same length - where you have json instead.

```
tmp <- lapply(seq_along(tmp), function(i){jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp[[i]][,2])})
```

You will of course need something else for the actual extraction of data into whatever final structure you are after.

The regex also needs adjusting as by being lazy it stops too short on some urls e.g. at page=7.

```
body_tags_1 <- lapply(paste0('https://www.eventbrite.com/d/ny--new-york/conference/?page=', 1:10),
                      function(url){
                        url %>% read_html() %>% 
                          html_nodes("body") %>% 
                          html_text() %>% 
                          toString() # to produce a single character string describing an R object.
                      })

tmp <- str_match_all(body_tags_1,'window\\.__SERVER_DATA__ = (.*);')  
tmp <- lapply(seq_along(tmp), function(i){jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp[[i]][,2])})
```

Tested for all 49 pages also using

```
tmp <- lapply(seq_along(tmp), function(i){jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp[[i]][,2], flatten=TRUE)})
```

Comment: this doesn't work either by itself or in a loop. I have tried ``` for (i in 1:49){
  tmp <- lapply(seq_along(tmp), function(i){jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp[[i]][,2])})
} and get this error: Error during wrapup: incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: hummm...it worked for small number. Let me have a look.

Comment: The regex needed altering. Tested for 10 links.

Comment: Yes I tried tmp <- lapply(seq_along(tmp), function(i){jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp[[i]][,2], flatten=TRUE)}) but when I try this command print(tmp$suggestions$events$name) the result is NULL. When I do View(x = tmp), tmp still seems to be nested

Comment: Fine. As I said before I still think you need to write a function to extract whatever you need. I doubt flatten = True unravels a deeply nested structure. But the above solves your immediate question does it not?

Comment: Yes it solves my immediate question but not how to extract the information needed

Comment: then perhaps ask a new question and show your expected output (at least several rows of it) so it is clear what you want to extract and in which format. I have been trying to answer your questions as posed.